# Why Can't I find the Volume of a Rotated Graph by Average Value Theorum?

Tags: calculus, volume

I am wondering why I get an incorrect answer when trying to find the volume of a rotated function about the x-axis when using the Average Value Theorem.

I want to find the volume of $y=\sqrt{x-2}$ as it is revolved around the $x-axis$ on $ x\in[2,6]$

Classic Calculus (area with disks)

$\int_2^6\left(\pi x - 2\pi\right)dx$

Why can't I do...

$4\pi\left(\frac14\int_2^6\sqrt{x-2}dx\right)^2$

Basically my plan is to create a cylinder with r = average radius.  It is using the volume for a cylinder $V=\pi r^2h$.  The version with variables looks like...

$\pi(a-b)\left(\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx\right)^2$

Comment: Relevant: Pappus' centroid theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem

Is this what you meant to apply?

Comment: No @cardboard_box The mean value theorem is very different form the average value theorem.  Mean value finds where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ equals the slope of the line from point $a$ to $b$.  Average value finds the average y value of $f$.

Comment: @JulienClancy Thank you that is very interesting, but I am wondering why my method does not work.  I'm looking for some type of math proof where my method fails.

Comment: The problem is that a cylinder's volume is proportional to the square of its radius, and the square of the average is not the average of the square.  If you found the average $ r^2 $ over that integral you'd be able to calculate the volume from this.

Comment: To add to @cardboard_box 's comment, the problem is sort of that the average radius is *not* where the centroid of the shape is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the computation of the average value of $y$ assigns equal weights to all of the $y$ values, but unlike the situation for areas, they don’t contribute equally to the volume.

The contribution of a particular $y$ value to the total area under a curve is directly proportional to $y$, and thus also directly proportional to $\Delta y=y-\bar y$, so replacing $y$ by $\bar y$, the unweighted average, is appropriate. For a volume of rotation, however, you have $dV=\pi y^2\,dx$, and $$\pi(y+\Delta y)^2-\pi\bar y^2 = \pi(2\bar y\Delta y+\Delta y^2),$$ which is nonlinear. You could, of course, use an average value to compute a volume of rotation, but it would have to be an appropriately-weighted one.